# Error in installation of older version of openssl

Tags: libraries, openssl, dynamic-linking, shared-library

I am trying to compile openssl 0.9.6 (I know very old version) from source on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I did following

> ./configure shared --openssldir=/home/segnate/dev/openssl
>
> make
>
> make install

On doing make install the installation failed with error like below

> installing libcrypto.so
>
> /usr/bin/ranlib: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so: File format not recognized

Similar error occurred for libcrypto.so.0 , libcrypto.so.0.9.6 , libssl.so , libssl.so.0 , libssl.so.0.9.6

How do I get rid of above error?

Comment: are you running the installation in a 64-bit machine ?

Comment: Don't do it (the installation). Keep it locally, and manually tell the different programs to use the old lib. Better not to mix old and new library in parallel (especially if it is an essential library, for your os)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi What this error is then exactly ?

Comment: @VishvajeetPatil I don't know, and the strange thing it is that it appears only on install.